# iPhone: How to add a scrollable text in a tab view

Tags: iphone, uitextview

Looking for some guidance.

In my main window nib file, i have a tab controller where each tab control item is being loaded by a separate nib file and controller. One of the tab items is being loaded by a navigation controller.
Looks like this (excuse me for not including screenshot)

- MainWindow.xib

  - Windows
  - UITabBarController

    - UITabBar
    - UINavigationController (loaded from Test.xib file)

      - TabBar Item
- Test.xib

  - View

Now I like to add a scrollable text in the Test.xib. So that when the user clicks on the tab item, my Test view opens up with some text that the user can scroll.

Do I need to add a UITextView as a child of my View in Test.xib ?
Do I need to add a UIScrollableView ? And how would I connect them all so that I can manage the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an `UITextView` to your view, connect it to a proper Outlet in your controller, than you can manipulate the text with `setText:`. The scrolling behaviour is added automatically.

Comment: Thanks @unset . There was something wrong with IB and I wasn't able to achieve it, with a new fresh view and the proper outlets as you mentioned, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UITextView needs to be a child of your View in Test.xib (you can add it programatically if you like or through IB). You do not need a UIScrollableView.  The textview will scroll as long as you set scrollEnabled = YES;

Not sure what you mean by "how would I connect them so I can manage the text".  You can send the UITextView a message of setText to whatever text you want in there.  Hope that helps some!

Comment: Thanks, I simply had to connect an outlet to get it working. Oh and somehow Interface builder wasn't adding my text view correctly. Now it's good.